# retrieve value from second activity

Tags: java, android

In my MainActivity, I launch a second activity:

```
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPush);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent nowStart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),      AddPillScheduleActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(nowStart, RESULT_OK);
            //startSecond();
        }
    });
```

Then inside my Second Activity, I would like to return a value back to the main activity.

```
      Intent i=new Intent();
            i.putExtra("ANSWER", ans);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
            finish();
```

That seems to execute fine, but back in my MainActivity, I would like to grab the value. This is where I am having trouble. My debugger never stops on my onActivityResult, which is:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode ,int resultCode ,Intent data ) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ANSWER");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Can someone shed a little light? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the value from the right intent, the one that comes with the method. Modify your code to the following:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode ,int resultCode ,Intent data ) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String name = data.getStringExtra("ANSWER");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 }
```

Use the [getStringExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)) method as you put a `String` in your intent and not a `bundle`. Also, not the best practice use the same code for the `requestCode` and `resultCode`.

Comment: I put this in my MainActivity, but the debugger doesn't break on it and I never get the Toast msg, although, I am redirected back to the MainActivity on the screen.

Comment: Updated my answer. Checkout if that solves it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ANSWER");
```

is accessing the wrong intent.  `getIntent()` returns the intent that started the activity.  You want

```
String name = data.getExtras().getString("ANSWER");
```

Also, the second parameter of `startActivityForResult()` is a request code, so using `RESULT_OK` -- althought it still works -- is confusing.